# ExtJs 4.2.1 tree - icon "loading" is not shown

Tags: css, extjs

on my page i have a tree view which is loading nodes asynchronously before expanding. I can't figure out how to display standard "loading" gif while waiting for node to load. I understand that it's standard behavior, but it simply wont work. Probably it's some css issue..

My page references css like this:

```
<link href="Scripts/app/ext-4/resources/ext-theme-classic/ext-theme-classic-all-debug.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I know it's there because everything else is rendered correctly. In that css file is this class:

```
.x-grid-tree-loading .x-tree-icon {
  background-image: url('images/tree/loading.gif');
}
```

I'm certain that this class is used because if i put `background-color: #ff0000;` instead of `background-image: url('images/tree/loading.gif');`, the place where icon should appear gets red background. I understand that icon url should be set relative to css location, and it is. This is part of my file structure:

- Scripts

  - app
  - ext-4

    - resources
    - ext-theme-classic

      - images

        - tree

          - loading.gif
      - ext-theme-classic-all-debug.css

Also, when i call that icon directly using img tag like this:

```
<img src="Scripts/app/ext-4/resources/ext-theme-classic/images/tree/loading.gif" />
```

loading icon is shown as expected.

Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT: RESOLVED**

I was able to figure out what was the problem. Since i was using custom icons for tree nodes (sorry for not mentioning that, i didn't think that was relevant), loading.gif was somehow showing underneath those icons. To resolve that, i changed

```
.x-grid-tree-loading .x-tree-icon {
  background-image: url('images/tree/loading.gif');
}
```

to

```
.x-grid-tree-loading .x-tree-icon {
  background-image: url('images/tree/loading.gif') !important;
}
```

Comment: In file structure I can see, that `tree` is not under `images`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I fixed that in the post.

Comment: Try to add `.x-grid-tree-loading` class to one of tree nodes via firebug or other developer tools, and then try to see what happens. Maybe icon has some offsets and this is reason why it is not visible.

Comment: I tried that. I was able to get red background, but no icon =(